# Partial derivatives Laplace operator, showing that is harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given is $f: \Re^2 \backslash \{0\} \to \Re $ such that for all $x \in \Re^2 \backslash \{0\}, f(x) = \log|x|$
Show that $f$ is harmonic. This is the solution but I can't understand it.
\begin{align}
{\partial^2}_{x_i} \log|x|= \frac{1}{2}{\partial^2}_{x_i} \log|x|^2 = \partial_{x_i} \left( \frac{x_i}{|x|^2} \right)= \frac{1}{|x|^2}-\frac{2x_i^2}{|x|^4}
\end{align}
so it follows
\begin{align}
\Delta \log|x| = \frac{2}{|x|^2} - 2 \sum_{i=1}^{2} \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^4}=\frac{2}{|x|^2}-\frac{2}{|x|^2}=0
\end{align}

The whole point is to show that $\Delta f$ is $0$.
But I don't get even the second step. $\frac{1}{2}{\partial^2}_{x_i} \log|x|^2 = \partial_{x_i} \left( \frac{x_i}{|x|^2} \right)$

Comment: From the fact that $\alpha \log x=\log (x^\alpha)$ for all $x\ge 0$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Do you know how to get second step? Because the first partial derivative I get $\frac{\log(x)}{x}$

Comment: If you are willing to use Complex Analysis this is immediate from the fact that real parts of analytic functions are harmonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\log(|x|^2)$, not $(\log|x|)^2$.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\log(|x|^2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\log(x_1^2+x_2^2)=\frac{2\,x_i}{|x|^2}.
$$